# Make a copy object of anonymous thread

Tags: java, multithreading, clone

I am new to multi-threading,

and I am currently work on passing a parameter into a Thread.

```
public class MyRunnable<T> implements Runnable{

protected T obj;

public MyRunnable(){
    obj= null;
}
@Override
public void run(){
    //do something
}

public void setObj(T obj){
    this.obj=obj;
}

public T getObj(){
    return obj;
}

}
```

And I am try to initialize a MyRunnable obj with specify task

within the public void run , like this.

```
someMethod(new MyRunnable<someType>(){
public void run(){
    // do some jobs 1.
        // do some jobs 2.
}
});
```

I want to use this runnable object for different threads with different obj value,
so is it possible to make a deep copy with the same run method?

Thanks in advance!

edit:
the original MyRunnable().run() does nothing, and the task is implemented within the anonymous block, is it any work around to make the copy with the same implemented run() method?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy constructor

```
public MyRunnable(MyRunnable myRunnable) {
    this.fieldA = myRunnable.fieldA;
    this.felddB = myRunnable.fieldB;
    // etc
}
```

Because you'd be using a different object (with all of the other fields being the same), modify the constructor to reflect this

```
public MyRunnable(T obj, MyRunnable myRunnable) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.fieldA = myRunnable.fieldA;
    this.felddB = myRUnnable.fieldB;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but I did overwrite the run method, so will that be copied as well?

Comment: The original run method does nothing, and I implement inside the anonymous block. I know I can always create a new class extends MyRunnable to fixed that,  but there are lots of the them, so creating  new classes will be a pain.

Comment: I think you are going about this all wrong, how many implementations of MyRunnable are there and what common functionality is shared between them (so much so that you need to extend MyRunnable)

Comment: All instances of MyRunnable will use the same run method. As an alternative, you can have a `Runnable runnable` field in MyRunnable, and then you can implement its runnable method as `void run() { if (runnable != null) runnable.run(); else // default run method }`, which will let you override the run method with an anonymous Runnable

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method that returns a particular type of MyRunnable:

```
public MyRunnable<SomeType> getRunnableForSomePurpose(){
    return new MyRunnable<SomeType>(){
        public void run(){
            //do some jobs
        }
    }
}
```

Then call that method each time you need a MyRunnable with that specific run method:

```
someMethod(getRunnableForSomePurpose());
```